# How to add a questi0n to a survey in the surveymonkey API

Tags: api, surveymonkey

I need to create "personally customized" surveys programmatically.

I know how to create a new survey from a template (create_flow), but can I then add customized questions to that survey?

And sorry for the "questi0n" in the title.  stack overflow won't let me use "question" in the title!  seriously.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint you're mentioning `create_flow` is a V2 endpoint, I would recommend using V3 of the SurveyMonkey API as V2 is likely being deprecated soon. Also V3 has a lot more functionality.

Look at the [docs for v3](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/). Particularly [creating surveys](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-pages-and-questions). You can create surveys with your survey data at the following endpoint:

```
POST /v3/surveys
```

Create a page at:

```
POST /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/pages
```

Create a question:

```
POST /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/pages/<page_id>/questions
```

You can update an existing question with

```
PATCH /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/pages/<page_id>/questions/<question_id>
```

Or replace it altogether at

```
PUT /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/pages/<page_id>/questions/<question_id>
```

Basically manipulate the survey however you'd like with a RESTful API. You can see in the docs the specific payload examples. I think it is a much better idea to use V3 to do what you want, I'm not sure what you are asking for is supported in V2.